How to show next Image from url without specifying width and height
I'm trying to show image in next js using import Image from 'next/image'; without specifying width and height.
Note that image is coming from URL and not from specific folder in project.
<Image     
sizes={"100vw"} 
width={0} 
height={0} 
src={'https://picsum.photos/200/300'} 
placeholder='empty'  />

This code works if I import image from folder but when trying to show image from URL it fails.
Anyone has idea how to render image without adding width and height property?
Also I want to preserve original size and not to fit image over all screen using fill and objectFit properties

you have to add the domain in next.config.js

in next/image you have to required width or height

By setting layout="fill", the image will take up the available space without specifying a fixed width and height. And by setting objectFit="none", the image will be displayed in its original size.
import Image from 'next/image';

<Image
  src={'https://picsum.photos/200/300'}
  layout="fill"
  objectFit="none"
  placeholder="empty"
/>


According to the Next.js documentation, you can specify the fill prop as fill = {true}. On the same doc link, you can find that as of version 13.0.0, layout and objectFit props have been removed.
import Image from 'next/image'
 
<Image
  fill
  sizes={"100vw"} 
  src="/example.png"
/>

